# How to solve this Java Warning & Compilation error for JPA-CriteriaAPI?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

[image: Java Warning in Eclipse]

If I declare like following it gives compilation error as follows :

[image: Java Compilation Error in Eclipse]

Answer (score 2):

`ParameterExpression<List<?>> vp=cb.parameter(List.class);`

if not working, leave raw type and add `@SuppressWarning('rawtypes');`

Comment: Yeah `@SuppressWarning('rawtypes');` is what I do

Comment: ParameterExpression<List<?>> does not help.

Comment: I am looking for alternative solution for @SuppressWarning('rawtypes');

Comment: It is not possible to provide construct like (List<whatever>.class) due to generic type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your question should have all the information which will convey your problem statment very clearly.
What I can guess from above image is that your are facing problem while creating ParameterExpression. And for that you can take a look at following sample code.

```
private List<Customer> findCustomerWithParam(String name) {
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Customer> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> customer = criteriaQuery.from(Customer.class);
ParameterExpression<String> nameParameter = cb.parameter(String.class, "name");
criteriaQuery.select(customer).where(cb.equal(customer.get("name"), nameParameter));
return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter("name", name).getResultList();
```

}

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my problem is not how to write Criteria Query with ParameterExpression, but it is about how to solve the warning and compilation errors shown in uploaded images.

Comment: Ohhh i see then you can go with @SuppressWarning('rawtypes');

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems using the following pattern

```
public <T> T f(Class<T> type) {
    return type.newInstance();
}
```

This does not yet work satisfactory for container classes.
An inefficient work-around would be to copy the list.

```
List<?> list0 = f(List.class);
List<String> list = list0.stream()
        .map(Objects::toString)
        //Or .map(s -> (String)s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So it is an API restriction.
I confess not being aware that the method `parameter` could deliver.